# How to add Error to payload for several key's value is null in payload in dataweave?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mule-component, mulesoft

I have a payload where I need to check for a few specific validation and if validation doesnt succeed I want to add an error to a new array in the payload.

Input :

```
[
  {
    "order": "123",
    "product": "",
    "invoice": "Lock"
    },
   {
    "order": "123",
    "product": "456",
    "invoice": ""
    }
    ]
```

In above input I need to check if Invoice == 'Locked' and Product != null, order needs to be checked against a different json array to see if that value exist but I just want to get an idea on invoice and product o how to get different validation and add errors to error array..

Expected output should be :

```
[
  {
    "order": "123",
    "product": "",
    "invoice": "Lock",
    "Errors" : {
      "Error" : true,
      "Error Message" : "Invoice is not "Locked", product is null"
      }
    },
   {
    "order": "123",
    "product": "456",
    "invoice": "123",
    "Errors" : {
      "Error" : false,
      "Error Message" : ""
      }
    }
    ]
```

**I want to be able to check for different validations for different keys.**

I am able to achieve below output, where I am using a different function for each individual key and adding error for each keys but it is becoming very challenging to filter out which error has occurred?

```
[
  {
    "order": "123",
    "product": "",
    "invoice": "",
    "Errors": {
      "Order ": "Order is NULL,",
      "Product": "",
      "Invoice": ""
      }
    },
   {
    "order": "123",
    "product": "456",
    "invoice": "123",
    "Errors": {
      "Order ": "",
      "Product": "",
      "Invoice": ""
      }
    }
    ]
```

Even if I can figure out from above output which one of the objects has errors in it, that will server the purpose.

How do I get the desired output shown above with `Errors` array with `{Error, error message}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the following DataWeave expression:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun addMessage(condition, message) = if (condition) message else null

fun validate(item) = 
    []
    << addMessage(isEmpty(item.order), "Order is null or empty")
    << addMessage(isEmpty(item.product), "Product is null or empty")
    << addMessage(isEmpty(item.invoice), "Invoice is null or empty")
    << addMessage(item.invoice ~= "Lock", "Invoice is locked")
    // keep adding other validation here

fun addError(messages) =
   {
       "Errors" : {
            "Error": !isEmpty(messages),
            "Error Message": ((messages filter (item) -> (item != null)) as Array) joinBy ", "
       }
   }

---
payload map (item, index) -> 
    item 
    ++  addError(validate(item))
```

It will produce the following output based on the provided example payload:

```
[
  {
    "order": "123",
    "product": "",
    "invoice": "Lock",
    "Errors": {
      "Error": true,
      "Error Message": "Product is null or empty, Invoice is locked"
    }
  },
  {
    "order": "123",
    "product": "456",
    "invoice": "",
    "Errors": {
      "Error": true,
      "Error Message": "Invoice is null or empty"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: let me try, I am already able to achieve something like this but by calling separate functions on each field in Errors object. Is there a way I can only add order, product or invoice in error object if there is an error?

Comment: I tried yours, the only difference in this and mine is that this will add different object for each error, I am either trying to achieve the expected output above or only add error to Errors object if validation fails, can you help ?

Comment: I did this which would give me nearly something what I want to add errors only if there is one but not sure if it's correct entirely.
`fun addError(condition, field, message) = 
    if(condition) {(field) : message} else "" `

Comment: I've updated my answer to try to achieve what you are looking for. Please, let me know if this works for you. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, adding `null` works but it still adds the key as the `if else ` is in the value of the key. Is there anyway I can avoid adding the key `invoice` it self if there is no error? The output of above code will have order and product both set to `null` but it will be in the array.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the expected output.

Comment: You are a savior, I made a few tweaks in this code and got what I wanted, thank you so much for leading me to right solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this script -

```html
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import someEntry from dw::core::Objects
fun maperror(item) = do {
    var error =  item someEntry (value, key) -> isEmpty(value)
    ---
    {
    "Error" : error,
    "Error Message" : if (error) keysOf((item filterObject ((value, key, index) -> isEmpty(value)))) map ($ ++ " is null") joinBy ", " else ""
    }
}
---
payload map {
    ($),
    "Errors": maperror($)
}
```

It will produce output like below -

```html
[
  {
    "order": "123",
    "product": "456",
    "invoice": "",
    "Errors": {
      "Error": true,
      "Error Message": "invoice is null"
    }
  },
  {
    "order": "123",
    "product": "",
    "invoice": "",
    "Errors": {
      "Error": true,
      "Error Message": "product is null, invoice is null"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This works but if I forgot to mention, multiple keys could have different validations other than only checking for null. I updated my question if you could please check.

Comment: @apple123 if different validations are needed for each key, then you can still continue on the approach shown in the answer. Instead of having `var error =  item someEntry (value, key) -> isEmpty(value)` as single, you can use pattern matching on the `key` and do key specific validations.

Comment: Could you please show a little example of it and how I can add specific error to that validation? Because adding validation will also require changing the error message in payload.

Comment: I tried adding match for key and comparing value to desired result I want but no luck. Can you give me a little snippet?

Comment: Can you update your questions with a few samples of what validations look like and against what keys in the input payload would those validations be done against?

Comment: @SalimKhan I updated the question below input I added what validations I require. There are more but I just want to get an idea on how to do each validation and add an error to error object if it fails. Thank you